# Загрузка файлов по Socket

Tags: файлы, сокет, c++

Всем доброго времени суток.

Я написал программу скачки файлов из интернета. Но она качает файлы не больше 104 mb. В чем проблема, не пойму.

Вопрос закрыт. Код переписал.  Вот код:

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

char bufRus[256];

char *rus(const char *text)
{
    CharToOem(text, bufRus);
    return bufRus;
}

int transfer(int sock, int fsockopen)
{

    FILE *stream;
    stream = fopen("new_file", "wb");
    int write;
    string cut;
    char get[512];
    float out = 1;
    int enter;

    cin.get();
    std::cout << rus("Çàïðîñ: ");
    getline(cin, cut);
    cut += "rnrn";
    send(sock, cut.data(), cut.length(), 0);
    recv(sock, get, 225, 0);
    cout << get;

    std::cout << rus("<<< Çàãðóçêà Ôàéëà Çàïóùåíà >>>") << endl;
    while (fsockopen == 0) {
        out = recv(sock, get, sizeof(get), 0);

        if (out == 0) {
            closesocket(sock);
            std::cout << endl << rus("<<< Âíèìàíèå: Çàôèêñèðîâàí (0) ðàçìåð ïðèíÿòûõ                              äàííûõ. >>>") << endl;

        }
        if (out == -1) {
            std::cout << endl << rus("<<< Îøèáêà ïðè ïåðåäà÷å ôàéëà. Ñîåäèíåíèå ðàçîâàíî >>>") << endl;
            closesocket(sock);

            cin >> enter;
            exit(0);
        }
        write = fwrite(&get, sizeof(get), 1, stream);

        /* Ошибка была в использовании функции ofstream.
           1. Функция замедляла работу программы. 
           2. Ошибка в максимальном размере записи.
           3. Замедляла скорость скачивания файла.
           Всем советую пользоватся функциями fopen, fwrite, fread ...
           Они больше подходят для работы с файлами. */

        cout << "011011010101010110100110101010101";
    }
    closesocket(sock);

    cin.get();
    exit(0);

}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Denloader Express v 1.0 BETA" << endl;

    string did;
    int fsockopen;
    char ip[15];
    int port = 80;

    WSADATA WsaData;
    if (int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaData) != 0) {
        cout << rus("Çàãðóçêà ñîåäèíåíèÿ íåóäàëàñü.") << endl;
    }
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (sock == -1) {
        std::cout << rus("Îøèáêà ñîçäàíèÿ ñîåäèíåíèÿ.");
    }
    do {
        std:cout << rus("IP àäðåññ: ");
        cin >> ip;

        sockaddr_in addr;
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

        fsockopen = connect(sock, (sockaddr *) & addr, sizeof(addr));
        if (fsockopen != 0) {

            std::cout << rus("Îøèáêà ïîäêëþ÷åíèÿ!");
            std::cout << rus("Ïîâòîðèòü ââîä àäðåñà?(y = äà/n = íåò) ");
            cin >> did;
        } else {
            std::cout << rus("Ïîäêëþ÷åíî...") << endl;
        }
    } while (did == "y");

    transfer(sock, fsockopen);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На ошибки после recv() и вывода в file_st проверять надо (и печатать, если появились).

Кстати, recv() возвращает количество полученных байт, которое не обязательно равно запрошенному, поэтом запись в file_st надо переделать. Если recv() вернула 0, то это конец данных (close() или shutdown() с той стороны), если -1 , то ошибка.

У Вас, как я вижу, винда - для получения кода ошибки вызывайте WSAGetLastError().

Перед написанием программ настоятельно рекомендую **внимательно читать** документацию.

Comment: @ltachi779, молодец. Проблема решена. OK.


            /* Ошибка была в использовании функции ofstream.
           1. Функция замедляла работу программы. 
           2. Ошибка в максимальном размере записи.
           3. Замедляла скорость скачивания файла.
           Всем советую пользоватся функциями fopen, fwrite, fread ...
           Они больше подходят для работы с файлами. */


От себя добавлю, что для многих программ Си подходит больше, чем C++.

Еще одно замечание:

    write = fwrite(&get, sizeof(get), 1, stream);

вместо sizeof надо писать реально полученное от recv() длину.

Comment: А это комментарий уже для @ХэшКод.

Последние строки длинного комментария (даже если он **не последний ** на странице) приходится набивать вслепую, текст уходит за нижний край.

Firefox 10.0.2

**С чего бы это ?**

Comment: @Itachi779, еще один совет. Для повышения скорости читайте (и пишите) блоками побольше. Скажем 64 килобайта. 512 байт маловато. (если конечно у Вас не какая-то особая ситуация).